# php convert string to SQL type DateTime

Tags: php, string, datetime, timestamp

I want to be able to compare an input of $date, which is a string, with a value from the database with the type of "datetime". Here's my code below.  It outputs as a string type instead of the desired datetime type.  Can you please help me out?

```
<?php
  $string="2013-04-19 14:08:10";
  $timestamp = strtotime($string);
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
?>
<?php var_dump($date);?>
```

this is the output

```
string '2013-04-19 14:08:10' (length=19)
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score -1):

for MySQL datetime data type you can use:

```
$date = new \DateTime('2013-04-19 14:08:10');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of how it should be compared to the SQL `datetime`.